# How do I format the gridlines of a chart using C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, excel-interop, office-automation

I want to add the MajorGridlines and the MinorGridlines for both the X and Y axes and do other formatting settings on the chart.

I already formated the chart with the ChartWizard, but the documentation doesn't explain how to use the interfaces like Gridlines or Axis to format a Chart object, I tried to Select() the chart but it gives me the error "0x800A03EC", and I tried to Activate() the chart and it gives me the same error.

This is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Graficador___v2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public object ActiveSheet { get; }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Declaramos objetos que van a guardar los datos actuales del archivo de Excel.
            Excel._Application currentApplication = null;
            Excel.Workbooks currentWorkbooks = null;
            Excel._Workbook currentWorkbook = null;
            Excel.Sheets currentWorksheets = null;
            Excel.Worksheet currentWorksheet = null;
            Excel.Range allTheCells = null;

            //Declaramos las variables para guardar los rangos de las ganancias y las frecuencias.
            Excel.Range[] rangesOfGains = new Excel.Range[5];
            Excel.Range rangeOfFrequencies = null;

            //Celdas dummy.
            Excel.Range dummyCell1 = null;
            Excel.Range dummyCell2 = null;
            Excel.Range dummyCell3 = null;
            Excel.Range dummyCell4 = null;

            //Para hacer la gráfica de ganancias.
            Excel.Chart GráficaFrecuenciaGanancia = null;
            Excel.ChartObject ObjetoGráficaFrecuenciaGanancia = null;
            Excel.ChartObjects ColecciónDeGráficasDummy = null;

            //Para las seires de la gráfica de ganancias.
            Excel.SeriesCollection ColecciónDeSeries = null;
            Excel.Series[] SeriesDeDatos = new Series[5];

            //Variable para indicar que el sistema falló en encontrar el archivo de Excel abierto.
            bool wasFoundRunning = false;

            
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //Checamos si Excel está abierto
            try
            {
                currentApplication = (Excel._Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"); //Guardamos la aplicación de Excel en tApp.
                wasFoundRunning = true; //Lo ponemos en true en caso de que sí esté abierto.
            }
            catch (Exception) //Excel no está abierto.
            {
                wasFoundRunning = false; //Lo ponemos en false en caso de que no esté abierto.
            }
            finally
            {
                if (wasFoundRunning) //Si no hubo excepciones.
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Found Excel opened file", "Success"); //Indicamos éxito.
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to get opened Excel file", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK); //Indicamos fracaso,
                }
            }

            currentWorkbooks = currentApplication.Workbooks; //Obtenemos la colección de los libros de trabajo abiertos de la aplicación Excel.
            currentWorkbook = currentWorkbooks.Item[1]; //Obtenemos el primer libro de trabajo abierto.
            currentWorksheets = currentWorkbook.Worksheets; //Obtenemos la única hoja de trabajo del libro de trabajo.
            currentWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)currentWorksheets.Item[1];
            allTheCells = currentWorksheet.Cells;

            //Asignamos las celdas a las variables especificadas.
            //Para las ganancias:
            dummyCell1 = allTheCells.Item[88, 2];
            dummyCell2 = allTheCells.Item[88 + 22, 2];
            //Para las frecuencias:
            dummyCell3 = allTheCells.Item[88, 1];
            dummyCell4 = allTheCells.Item[88 + 22, 1];

            //Creamos el rango de las celdas que contienen las frecuencias.
            rangeOfFrequencies = allTheCells.Range[dummyCell3, dummyCell4];

            //Ciclo For para guardar los rangos de las celdas para las ganancias.
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                rangesOfGains[i] =  allTheCells.Range[dummyCell1, dummyCell2];
                dummyCell1 = allTheCells.Item[dummyCell1.Row, dummyCell1.Column + 4];
                dummyCell2 = allTheCells.Item[dummyCell2.Row, dummyCell2.Column + 4];
            }

            //Creamos una colección de gráficas objeto, para obtener un objeto de ellas y luego crear una gráfica con el objeto.
            ColecciónDeGráficasDummy = (Excel.ChartObjects)currentWorksheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
            ObjetoGráficaFrecuenciaGanancia = ColecciónDeGráficasDummy.Add(10, 30, 1008, 680.315);
            GráficaFrecuenciaGanancia = ObjetoGráficaFrecuenciaGanancia.Chart;
            GráficaFrecuenciaGanancia.ChartWizard(
                Gallery: XlChartType.xlLineMarkers,
                PlotBy: XlRowCol.xlColumns,
                CategoryLabels: 21,
                SeriesLabels: 4,
                HasLegend: true,
                Title: allTheCells.Item[85, 1].Value,
                CategoryTitle: "Frecuencias (Hz)",
                ValueTitle: "Ganancias (dB)",
                ExtraTitle: "Extra"
                );
           
            //Hacemos las series de datos
            ColecciónDeSeries = GráficaFrecuenciaGanancia.SeriesCollection(Type.Missing); //Obtenenmos la colección de series de la gráfica.
            
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                SeriesDeDatos[i] = ColecciónDeSeries.NewSeries();
                SeriesDeDatos[i].XValues = rangeOfFrequencies.Cells;
                SeriesDeDatos[i].Values = rangesOfGains[i];
                SeriesDeDatos[i].Name = "Mediciones #" + (i+1).ToString();
            
            }

            GráficaFrecuenciaGanancia.Activate();
                        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a Chart object `GráficaFrecuenciaGanancia` so follow this link for the docs  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.axes

Comment: If you don't know what properties or methods should be used to get the job done, you can try recording a VBA macro using the macro recorder available in Excel. As a result, you will get a VBA macro with the required sequence of property and method calls. See [Automate tasks with the Macro Recorder](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b).

Comment: @DS_London Even though it is VB it actually showed me how to use the object model of Interop.Excel. Thanks.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I had a hard time using the macros of Excel, but I made it work thanks to the advice of DS_London.

Comment: The Excel object model is common for all programming languages, including VBA, so that is just a fast and convenient way to find the required properties and methods.